# Kubernetes Cronjob not picking up values provided by Hashicorp Vault Agent Injector

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

Hit a brick wall with exploring any more options with this so any help is greatly appreciated.

I've setup a new cronjob within a K8s namespace on GKE, modelled on existing cronjobs.  Basically the job executes a python program utilising environment variables from `os.env` which are fed from a ConfigMap for general variables and secets obtained from self-hosted Hashicorp Vault via the Vault Agent Injector.

The Cronjob contains the following annotations:

```
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-secrets-jira.env: tarsier/jira-data-loader-secret/rc
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-secrets-snowflake.env: tarsier/jira-data-loader-secret/rc
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-secrets.env: tarsier/jira-data-loader-secret/rc
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-secrets.env: |
      {{- with secret "tarsier/jira-data-loader-secret/rc" -}}
        export JIRA_TOKEN="{{ .Data.data.jira_account }}"
      {{- end }}
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-pre-populate-only: "true"
    vault.hashicorp.com/role: app-tarsier
    vault.hashicorp.com/secret-volume-path: /var/secrets
```

Thus, the role uses the same `app-tarsier` role defined in Vault to access the Secrets Engine (as every other cronjob in  the `tarsier` namespace.

The Vault pull appears to work as the file rendered into `/var/secrets` shows the key-value.  As I understand, the annotation should export the returned value into the listed environment variable to be made available to the container program.

This configuration has been compared to another cronjob whivh is working successfully.  However, the environment variable for `JIRA_TOKEN` is null when interrogated by the python program.

Not sure what i'm misunderstanding or missing here.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some troubleshooting steps and considerations that can can help you identify the problem:

1- Check Environment Variable Name: Double-check that the environment variable name in the Python program matches the one set in the vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-secrets.env annotation. In this case, ensure that the Python program is looking for `JIRA_TOKEN` as the environment variable.

2- Check Container Environment: Verify that the environment variable is indeed present within the container. You can do this by  running env or printenv commands to check the available environment variables.

```
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -n <namespace> -- env
```

PS: This only works if the Job is still `running`. It’s not possible to connect to Pods that belong to Completed jobs

3- Check Python Code: Review the Python code and make sure that it is correctly accessing the environment variable `JIRA_TOKEN`. Ensure that the environment variable is being read using the appropriate method in the Python code.

4- Check Vault Agent Logs: Check the logs of the Vault Agent to see if there are any error messages or warnings related to the injection of secrets. This might provide valuable insights into any potential issues.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: I have faced similar issue before, I have debugged using these steps, and YES it was formulated by AI to be grammatically correct